# Exception occurs when org.mybatis.spring.batch.MyBatisBatchItemWriter is used with oracle database

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, batch-processing, mybatis

Has anyone ever used `MyBatisBatchItemWriter` with oracle database?

When I set commit-interval as 2, protocol violation exception is raised.
I used `ResourcelessTrnasactionManager` and `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`.

It works fine with MySQL.
Even `JdbcBatchItemWriter` works fine with oracle database.
Only `MyBatisBatchItemWriter` with oracle database causes the exception.

Exception log is as follows.

```
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.194|DEBUG|o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep:TaskletStep.java:doInTransaction:437]    Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=240, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.194|DEBUG|o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager:AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:handleExistingTransaction:471]  Participating in existing transaction
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.195|DEBUG|o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep:TaskletStep.java:doInTransaction:451]    Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=3, version=7, name=putData, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=3240, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=7, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.195|DEBUG|o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager:AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:handleExistingTransaction:471]  Participating in existing transaction
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.196|DEBUG|org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils:Slf4jImpl.java:debug:47]  Transaction synchronization flushing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@109a2025]
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.196|DEBUG|o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager:AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:processCommit:753]  Initiating transaction commit
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.196|DEBUG|o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager:ResourcelessTransactionManager.java:doCommit:37]    Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@288ca5f0]
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.196|DEBUG|org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils:Slf4jImpl.java:debug:47]  Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@109a2025]
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.196|DEBUG|org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils:Slf4jImpl.java:debug:47]  Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@109a2025]
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.196|DEBUG|o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:DataSourceUtils.java:doReleaseConnection:327]    Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.197|ERROR|jdbc.sqltiming:Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.java:exceptionOccured:116]   7. Connection.close()
java.sql.SQLException: protocol violation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:459) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:61) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:498) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:3915) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy.close(ConnectionSpy.java:896) ~[log4jdbc-remix-0.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doCloseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:341) [spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:328) [spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:294) [spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils$ConnectionSynchronization.afterCompletion(DataSourceUtils.java:476) [spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:168) [spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:994) [spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:969) [spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:800) [spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724) [spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:148) [spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49) [spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.skplanet.storeplatform.batch.sac.common.main.BasicBatchRunnerMain.run(BasicBatchRunnerMain.java:60) [classes/:na]
    at com.skplanet.storeplatform.batch.sac.common.main.BasicBatchRunnerMain.main(BasicBatchRunnerMain.java:45) [classes/:na]
[2015-01-20 17:27:53.197|DEBUG|o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:DataSourceUtils.java:releaseConnection:297]  Could not close JDBC Connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mybatis bug. For now, change mybatis tag from `<insert>` to `<update>` in mapper file.